# How do I react to a window losing/gaining focus in AHK?

Tags: autohotkey

I play Guild Wars 2 and there's a function to show the names of items that can be interacted with, but the key has to be held down. I'm making it into a toggle, but I'd like for it to work even after swapping back and forth between windows.

After rebinding the function to F3 in-game, toggling the key seems as simple as this script:

```
#IfWinActive Guild Wars 2
LAlt::
    if (GetKeyState("F3")) {
        Send, {F3 up}
    } else {
        Send, {F3 down}
    }
#IfWinActive
```

However, when the window loses focus, I'm assuming the key is held down since when it regains focus, I need to hit the toggle twice for it to start showing what I want, again.

Ideally, I want a way for the key to be released when the window loses focus and pressed down again when the window regains focus. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You could poll the WinActive status in a separate loop and then take action if the active window changes.  Alternately you could still use a separate loop, but use WinWaitNotActive and WinWaitActive to take action as needed.  In other words, you check to see which window is active (get the currently active window) and then wait for it to not be active before doing anything else.  Once it's not active, you check for the active window again, do something appropriate if it's the right window, and then go back to waiting for that window to no longer be active.

To activate the separate loop only when F3 is enabled, you could use SetTimer to enable/disable repetitive execution of a separate routine, or just use a shared variable that is checked repeatedly, where the shared variable state changes state at the same time you send F3 up or down in the code you posted.